# Add a shortcode in woo-function.php

Tags: shortcode

I want to add the shortcode to log in and register.I already have the shortcode all I want to know is how can I add that for login and registration?

```
    if (!function_exists('techstore_tiny_account')) {

function techstore_tiny_account($icon = false) {
    $login_url = '#';
    $register_url = '#';
    $profile_url = '#';
    $logout_url = wp_logout_url(get_permalink());

    if (techstore_has_woocommerce()) { /* Active woocommerce */
        $myaccount_page_id = get_option('woocommerce_myaccount_page_id');
        if ($myaccount_page_id) {
            $login_url = get_permalink($myaccount_page_id);
            $register_url = $login_url;
            $profile_url = $login_url;
        }
    } else {
        $login_url = wp_login_url();
        $register_url = wp_registration_url();
        $profile_url = admin_url('profile.php');
    }

    $redirect_to = (is_ssl() ? 'https://' : 'http://') . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

    $result = '';
    if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
        $span = $icon ? '<span class="pe7-icon pe-7s-lock"></span>' : '';
        $result .= '<li class="menu-item color"><a href="' . esc_url($login_url) . '" title="' . esc_html__('Login or Register', 'techstore-theme') . '">' . $span . esc_html__('Login or Register', 'techstore-theme') . '</a></li>';
    } else {
        $span1 = $icon ? '<span class="pe7-icon pe-7s-user"></span>' : '';
        $span2 = $icon ? '<span class="pe7-icon pe-7s-unlock"></span>' : '';
        $result .= 
            '<li class="menu-item"><a href="' . esc_url($profile_url) . '" title="' . esc_html__('My Account', 'techstore-theme') . '">' . $span1 . esc_html__('My Account', 'techstore-theme') . '</a></li>' .
            '<li class="menu-item"><a class="nav-top-link" href="' . esc_url($logout_url) . '" title="' . esc_html__('Logout', 'techstore-theme') . '">' . $span2 . esc_html__('Logout', 'techstore-theme') . '</a></li>';
    }

    return $result;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a shortcode in that code. Shortcodes are created using the add_shortcode function. What are you actually trying to do with the above code?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. I have a signup and login popup plugin shortcode i want to add that. But i have no idea where to add that.

Comment: The shortcode is:  [lsphe-header]